# JavaScript Bingo Game - Make Cells Clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the HTML code I'm implementing to generate a Bingo card:

```
...
                    <th class="orange">B</th>
                    <th class="orange">I</th>
                    <th class="orange">N</th>
                    <th class="orange">G</th>
                    <th class="orange">O</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="square0"> &nbsp;</td>
                    <td id="square1"> &nbsp;</td>
                    <td id="square2"> &nbsp;</td>
                    <td id="square3"> &nbsp;</td>
                    <td id="square4"> &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>

                ...
```

I was wondering **how can I make it so that the cells (namely, 'td') are clickable and will trigger a function to change colour in the .js file?**

Here's the .js file I have:

```
var usedNums = new Array(76);

function newCard() {
    //Starting loop through each square card
    for(var i=0; i < 24; i++) {  //<--always this code for loops. change in red
        setSquare(i);
    }
}

function setSquare(thisSquare) {
    var currSquare = "square"+thisSquare;
    var newNum;

    var colPlace =new Array(0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4);

    do {
        newNum =(colPlace[thisSquare] * 15) + getNewNum() + 1;
    }
    while (usedNums[newNum]);

    usedNums[newNum] = true;
    document.getElementById(currSquare).innerHTML = newNum;
}

function getNewNum() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 75);

}

function anotherCard() {
    for(var i=1; i<usedNums.length; i++) {
    usedNums[i] = false;
    }

    newCard();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you in the right direction, HTML:

```
<table class="coolTable">
  <tr>
    <th class="orange">B</th>
    <th class="orange">I</th>
    <th class="orange">N</th>
    <th class="orange">G</th>
    <th class="orange">O</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="square0"> x</td>
    <td id="square1"> x</td>
    <td id="square2"> x</td>
    <td id="square3"> x</td>
    <td id="square4"> x</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', 'td', function() {
    //To change properties of the clicked cell
  $(this).css("background-color", "black");
  $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
  $(this).css('color', 'red');

  //To call a function, or manipulate a function
  newCard();
  //To manipulate a function
  newCard("manipulated a function");
});

function newCard(x) {
    if (x){
    alert(x);
  }
    else{
    alert("called a function");
  }
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jc6w1xb/1/)

Comment: Thanks :) I can see it when I try it out in the JSfiddle but when I put the code $(document)...in my .js file and ran the program I still can't click the cell. Is putting the JQuery in the .js file all you need to do?

Comment: @RosaryLightningX You're welcome, I will update my answer soon, but I'm curious to know the reasoning behind the downvote.

Comment: @RosaryLightningX I didn't fully understand your question, so I edited my answer based on my interpretation of what you might mean. For example I have no idea what you mean by "change colour in the js file", is there a variable in the js file that represents colour? or do you mean change the colour of the cell through js when it is clicked? Because of vagueness, I posted a broad answer. JSFiddle is updated also. Hope it helps.

Comment: By the way, you tagged jquery so this is a jquery answer. You need to link jquery for it to work.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I will try out your new answer :) I tagged jQuery mainly because it was suggested and based on some of the other answers it seems like jQuery was the preferable method. Is there anything I can do to make the question clearer?

Comment: By linking jQuery do you mean if I have this line of code or similar? <script type="text/javascript" src="gamejs.js"></script>

Comment: I played around with the code a bit more and I got it now.  I got inspired by your code even though I didn't actually get to use jQuery.  I basically just did: <td><button id="square0" class = "square"> &nbsp;</button></td>.  I'll work on that for a bit and then I'll come back.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: You link JQuery by adding the following tag on your head tag: `<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script></head>`

Comment: I see, thank you! I checked over my code again, and I didn't have that linking code.

Answer (score 1):

I would just add a button element inside the td element, and then handle it as such.

Comment: Can you elaborate? So I tried something like "<td id="square0" type = "button" onclick = "HelloWorld()"> &nbsp;</td>" and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Sorry.  Yes, I was trying to say to wrap a button in the td.  So not type = but another element altogether.  But that other answer looks good too, if it works :)

Comment: Ah...okay I kind of see what you mean. Not sure about the exact implementation however. Is there a page that could give me some more details?

Comment: I got it now by using <td><button id="square0" class = "square"> &nbsp;</button></td>. Let's hope it's a good implementation.